# Is there any formal way or known way to canonicalize an xml file to generate diffs?

Tags: xml, version-control, unix, diff

There seems to be many questions WRT tool to generate diffs between xmls, but there wasn't this question yet, so anyone who knows this show me a link or paste any example anyone already solved this problem.

Canonicalizing an xml file means,

- reordering the appearance of attributes
- reordering the appearance of tags (selectable by command line option)
- insert line ending(CR/CR+LF/LF) if there isn't at the end of a close tag
- insert indentation tab(space)
- remove redundant spaces and line endings

And then you can cleanly diff the xml files to see which part was updated.

I want to use the routine to canonicalize in unix environment, as quick as possible, before checking in to version control repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) has a canonicalization mode (`c14n`).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this it was a standard... since 2001, and implemented in 2004 in XMLStarlet. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you could use the xmldiff tool: [Using the XML Diff and Patch Tool in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)

[The XML Diff and Patch GUI Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx)

Comment: Surprised how quick this answer was, but unfortunately this is not the answer I was expecting. I want to use the routine to canonicalize in unix environment, as quick as possible, before checking in to version control repository.